# php how to grouping by id

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm very new in PHP. I'm doing with the array data structure. Currently, I got two result which is the same ID but different details. I need to combine the details based on the ID.

This is my array result

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:13 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "01-02-2019"
    "order" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F001"
        "name" => "fish"
      ]
    ]
  ]

  1 => array:13 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "01-02-2019"
    "order" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F002"
        "name" => "chicken"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

This is my expected result

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:13 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "01-02-2019"
    "order" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F001"
        "name" => "fish"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F002"
        "name" => "chicken"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I'm trying to insert the order array if there have the same id

This is my code

```
public function order($value)
    {
        $group_id = [];
    $groupItem = [];
    foreach ($value as $item) {
        $item['date'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['date']));
        $groupItem = $item['order'][] = [
                     'id' => $item['id'],
                     'name' => $item['name'],
                       ];

        $group_id[$item['id']][]= $groupItem; 
    }
}
```

Result

```
array:1 [
  "1" => array:1 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F001"
        "name" => "fish"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "code" => "F002"
        "name" => "chicken"
      ]
    ]
]
```

As you can see, I grouped the `order` but the date and id were missing.

Comment: Can your input have _different_ IDs? As in do you need to do this for multiple different items in input or they always belong to same ID and just need order part combined?

Comment: Yeah, my input can be `different`IDs. It will combine if there have `same` IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working order function:

```
function order($input) {
    $output = array();
    foreach($input as $item) {
        if (!isset($output[$item['id']])) {
            $output[$item['id']] = array(
                "id" => $item["id"],
                "date" => $item["date"],
                "order" => array()
            );
        }
        $output[$item['id']]['order'][] = $item['order'];
    }
    return array_values($output);
}
```

INPUT:

```
array(
  array(
    "id" => "1",
    "date" => "01-02-2019",
    "order" => array(
      array(
        "code" => "F001",
        "name" => "fish"
      )
    )
  ),

  array(
    "id" => "1",
    "date" => "01-02-2019",
    "order" => array(
      array(
        "code" => "F002",
        "name" => "chicken"
      )
    )
  )
);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(
  array(
    "id"=> "1",
    "date"=> "01-02-2019",
    "order"=> array(
      array(
        array(
          "code"=> "F001",
          "name"=> "fish"
        )
      ),
      array(
        array(
          "code"=> "F002",
          "name"=> "chicken"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the proper data. Try -

```
foreach ($value as $item) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($item['date']));
    $id = $item['id'];
    $group_id[$id]['id'] = $id;
    $group_id[$id]['date'] = $date;
    $group_id[$id]['order'][] = [
         'id' => $item['id'],
         'name' => $item['name'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this, if you need to account for multiple IDs:

```php
$result = array_reduce( $input, function ( $result, $item ) {
    $id = $item['id'];

    if ( ! isset( $result[ $id ] ) ) { // We don't have an item yet.
        $result[ $id ] = $item;
    } else { // We have an item and need to add orders to it.
        $result[ $id ]['order'] = array_merge( $result[ $id ]['order'], $item['order'] );
    }

    return $result;
}, [] );
```